# Why is it `sample0` not `sample` inside `cv.glm`?

Tags: r, cross-validation, glm

I am going through the source code for `cv.glm` from `boot`. There is one line

```
s <- sample0(rep(1L:K, f), n)
```

I looked up `sample0`, but it doesn't exist. I believe it really means `sample()`. Why is it entered as `sample0` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at:

```
boot:::sample0
#function (x, ...) 
#x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]
#<bytecode: 0xa2a30e4>
#<environment: namespace:boot>
```

This is an internal / non-exported function in the namespace of `boot`.